# Notifications badge doesn't go away after notifications get read?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

This is my notification icon markup in the navbar, this doesn't remove the badge with the count of unread notifications after reading the notifications:

```
const notificationsIcon =
     notifications && notifications.length && notifications.filter(n => !n.read).length ?
         <Badge badgeContent={notifications.filter(n => !n.read).length}>
             <NotificationsIcon /> //Material-UI Icon
         </Badge> : <NotificationsIcon />
```

But this works:

```
let notificationsIcon;
        if (notifications && notifications.length > 0) {
            notifications.filter(n => n.read === false).length > 0
                ? (notificationsIcon = (
                    <Badge
                        badgeContent={
                            notifications.filter(n => n.read === false).length
                        }
                    >
                        <NotificationsIcon />
                    </Badge>
                ))
                : (notificationsIcon = <NotificationsIcon />);
        } else {
            notificationsIcon = <NotificationsIcon />;
        }
```

I really can't understand why the second markup works while the first not,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  notifications: state.user.notifications
})
```

`notificationsIcon` variable would be wrapped in render method with a Material-UI element `IconButton` which when clicked send an action to redux store to change notifications `read` properties to true and this would update the notifications in the component.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this just for testing your 1st logic, this works:

```js
let notifications = [{read: true}, {read: true}]
const notificationsIcon =
     notifications && notifications.length && notifications.filter(n => !n.read).length ?
         "yes" : "no";
         console.log(notificationsIcon);
```

Can't try with actual code, can you provide stackblitz or plunker.
And try this as well:

```
const notificationsIcon =
 notifications && notifications.length && notifications.filter(n => !n.read).length ?
     (<Badge badgeContent={notifications.filter(n => !n.read).length}>
         <NotificationsIcon /> //Material-UI Icon
     </Badge>) : (<NotificationsIcon />);
```